# How to fetch completed task though Asana API in PHP

Tags: php, asana, asana-api

I written code so far:

```
$projectId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$tasks = $asana->getCompletedTasks($projectId);
```

Function call

```
public function getCompletedTasks($projectId){                                            
  return $this->askAsana($this->projectsUrl."/{$projectId}/tasks?completed=true");
}
```

But it gets all completed & incomplete tasks. I want to fetch only completed tasks. Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query) is the list of valid query parameters for tasks. Unfortunately, `completed` is not currently supported.

You can use `completed_since=now` to retrieve only *incomplete* tasks. However, there is no server side method for retrieving only *completed* tasks.

The best way to accomplish this would be to get all tasks for the project, using [pagination](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/pagination) to ensure efficient and full coverage. Then perform client-side filtering on the `completed` field of each task.

Remember that query results are returned in compact form (`id` & `name`) and you should use [field selectors](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options) to have additional fields such as `completed` included in the payload.